# Lightning - CSP and Client Side Callout

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps

I was reviewing lightning document, it seems the framework is currently limited to make callout only through apex, I understand this is done for security reasons, I feel its a big limitation while we compare with VF and other framework for adoption, it will also result in un-necessary server side code written and compatibility problem with existing projects like ForceTk, etc is a problem, Is there any plan to relax this restriction in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the same pain as you do and asked already a similar question which is answered by Doug here

[Lightning: is direct API access on the roadmap?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68124/lightning-is-direct-api-access-on-the-roadmap)

As to my knowledge this is still up to date and therefore not sure, if or when this constraint might be relaxed.

Comment: Thanks!, so for short term there is no clear roadmap

Comment: My guess: for short term it will stay as it is.

Comment: the performance reason given is vague though, since the client code executes on browser side.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to call external API using Javascript from within Salesforce Lightning.

Start by going to **Setup → CSP Trusted Sites** and adding your trusted site.

Which in this example is: https://api.postcodes.io/

Then use an approach like this:

```
({
    postcodeSearch : function(component, postcode) {
        var url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + postcode;
        this.makeAjaxRequest(component, url);
    },
    callAjax : function(method, url, async, callback) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(component) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
                callback.call(this, xmlhttp);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open(method, url, async);
        xmlhttp.send();
    },
    makeAjaxRequest : function(component, url) {
        this.callAjax("GET", url, true,
                      function(xmlhttp){
                          if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                              console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                          }
                          else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                              console.log("makeAjaxRequest: 400 Error");
                          }else {
                              console.log("makeAjaxRequest: Error");
                          }
                      }
                     );
    }
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I still get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/XAV. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` even with adding my site to CSP.

Comment: @TylerZika the error message says you are missing CORS which can be set via `Setup > CORS > New > Enter an orgin URL pattern`