# Getting Session ID in Lightning

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, lightning, session, lightning-experience

**Background**

I'm using [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to update some picklist values on the fly. (i.e. Every time a record is inserted/updated/deleted in Table A, I'm adding/subtracting picklist values into a MultiselectePicklist in table B).

Since,

> An Apex trigger can execute a callout when the callout is invoked within a method defined as asynchronous: that is, defined with the @future keyword.

I implemented a method with the future annotation, and

> For Apex code that is executed asynchronously, such as @future methods, Batch Apex jobs, or scheduled Apex jobs, getSessionId returns null.

so, I needed to pass the session Id as a parameter in the method, I implemented something like:

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void addContactPicklistPreference(List<String> preferences, String sessionId){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjectDescribe = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    String picklistFieldName = 'Preference__c';              

    Picklist_MDT.addPicklistValues(sObjectDescribe, picklistFieldName, artists, sessionId);
}

public class Picklist_MDT { 
    public static void addPicklistValues(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjectDescribe, String picklistFieldName, List<String> picklistValueNames, String sessionId) {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService(sessionId);
        ...    
    }

     public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(String sessionId) {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = sessionId;
        return service;
    }
}
```

And called the `addContactPicklistPreference` method from trigger context passing it the `UserInfo.getSessionId()` value.

**Problem**

This worked just fine in salesforce classic but **not in lightning**, when it triggers in lightning I'm getting `System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID...`. Funny thing is that if I put a `System.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId());` before calling the `addContactPicklistPreference` method it prints a valid session Id in both classic and lightning.

I would really appreciate any input about this.

Comment: Lightning renders from different domain ?Is that related to causing this issue .

Comment: Here is another answer that reflects a bit on how the Session ID in lightning is special. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68124/lightning-is-direct-api-access-on-the-roadmap

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So, as it turns outs there is no way of getting a valid API-capable Session Id from lightning component, here is a quote from the partner discussion forums:

> Three things:
>
> 1. There's no $Api global variable in Lightning Components today. So, {! $Api.whatever } will always fail.
> 2. This is intentional at this time. There's no official/supported way to get an API-capable session ID in Lightning Components. Again, this is by design.
> 3. With only a little creativity and cleverness you can create a bare-bones Visualforce page with {! $Api.SessionID }, and then call getContent(thatPage) from Apex to get a page that contains an API-capable session ID, which you should be able to parse out easily enough.
>
> From there, it's not hard to pass that session ID along to Lightning Components via an @AuraEnabled method.
>
> But let's be clear: this is a hack, the performance will be poor, and there's good reasons to keep an API-capable session ID out of your Lightning Components code.

So, I ended-up building the not recommended hack as a workaround for this to work in Lightning.

Just create a simple Visualforce Page as:

```
<apex:page>
    Start_Of_Session_Id{!$Api.Session_ID}End_Of_Session_Id
</apex:page>
```

And then get the Session Id with the `visualforce_Page.getContent()` method, something like:

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    //service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = Utils.getSessionIdFromVFPage(Page.SessionId);
    return service;
}
```

Where

```
global class Utils {
    global static String getSessionIdFromVFPage(PageReference visualforcePage){
        String content = visualforcePage.getContent().toString();
        Integer s = content.indexOf('Start_Of_Session_Id') + 'Start_Of_Session_Id'.length(),
                e = content.indexOf('End_Of_Session_Id');
        return content.substring(s, e);
    }
}
```

And then you got a valid session id to work with.

Comment: interesting...amounts to the same, but I created a page like this, makes parsing a bit easier `<apex:page contentType="application/json" >
    {
     "sessionId": "{!$Api.Session_ID}"
    }
</apex:page>`

Comment: I have same requirement and I am using your trick but I am getting some error Page session id Doesn't exist . cloud you please help me .

Comment: @NagarajaSV I think your org is having Lightning locker service enabled. This approach will not work with locker service enabled.

Comment: One way I think might work, but haven't tried.  Try firing up the event with session Id as param from vf page and then catch that in lightning component and assign it to an attribute.

Comment: Hi @NagarajaSV, do you have 'My Domain' (under Setup - Domain Management - My Domain) enable? This will prevent you from making a callout to the same domain so the MetadataService won't work.

Comment: Hi @JaiChaturvedi I actually have the Lightning Locker Service enabled and is working as expected.

Answer (score 12):

There is a Salesforce-accepted way to do this. Use a Named Credential along with a Connected App and Auth Provider (which will be Salesforce). The Named Credential will be used as your endpoint instead of the hardcoded URL. You'll still manually set the Session ID, but it will be to a merge field from the Named Credential. This blog walks through every step of the process, and I can confirm I was able to get it to work this way: https://gscloudsolutions.com/tips-tricks/using-named-credentials-with-the-apex-wrapper-salesforce-metadata-api/

Your createService() method will look like this:

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId ='{!$Credential.OAuthToken}';
    return service;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Per the LWC docs (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_api_calls_apex), "By security policy, sessions created by Lightning components aren’t enabled for API access."  That page explicitly mentions Named Credential as the correct way to make API calls from Lightning Components.

Answer (score 7):

According to the known issue [Summer'17- Generating a Session Id from Lightning Domain Provides Invalid Session Id](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAUPQA4&title=summer-17-generating-a-session-id-from-lightning-domain-provides-invalid-session-id) (W-3981698) it should be possible to pass `UserInfo.getSessionId()` out to lightning component via an @AuraEnabled an use it for API calls.

This *should* be possible from Winter '18 onward.

Comment: I say *should* here as I've had someone tell me this still isn't working for them.

Comment: `UserInfo.getSessionId()` doesn't work in Summer 18

Comment: Can anyone please confirm if this is actually fixed. I am on ApiVersion 45.
From lightning component, I am calling controller, which in turn calls the MetadataService class to deploy trigger metadata. In metadata service I am using "UserInfo.getSessionId()" but still getting the same error as mentioned here.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Its still not working as of 47.0

Comment: Well, in Summer'20 I am getting a value from Apex in Javascript. However, good luck trying to use that session id, as all I get are errors: This session is not valid for use with the REST API.

Comment: @SanderdeJong did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @IgorVasylevskyi No, I solved my particular problem in a completely different way so that I no longer needed the session id.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your Lightning Component is in a Flow Screen, you can retrieve the SessionId using a Flow formula with $Api.Session_ID and then pass it into the lightning component.

Comment: Is it security approved to do this way ?

Comment: No, since the Api Session Id is exposed to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few ways to accomplish this requirement.

1. use Named Credentials, and leverage the merge field `'{!$Credential.OAuthToken}';`
2. Create Visualforce page and access the sessionId from the content.
3. Create an auto launched flow that accesses the `{!$Api.Session_ID}` as a Formula field, then use `Flow.Interview` to invoke the flow, then use get variable value to retrieve the variable value.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is pretty old and has been answered.  However, I found a better fix for Apex that doesn't include the Visualforce hack. So I thought I would post it here for others if they come across this.

Simply place all your callouts into an internal wrapper class, making sure to set the sessionID = UserInfo.getUserId() inside the subclass, not from the controller.  This apparently removes the user's session ID far enough away from the controller that it gets the correct one for the call.  At least this works for me when trying to access the Tooling API.

```
public class MyController{

  public void getData()
  {
       ToolingClient clt = new ToolingClient();
       ToolingClient.ReturnResult = clt.getmyData();
       //do what you want with the data
  }
  public class ToolingClient{
    public ToolingClient(String strSessionId)
    {
        // set timeout
        this.timeout_x = 60 * 1000;
        //this.SessionHeader.sessionId = strSessionId;

        this.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        this.endpoint_x = RemoteSiteController.getApiUrl() + '/services/Soap/T/48.0';
    }
  //put all the callouts 
   }
```

}

Comment: This did not work for me in v52 making a callout to the metadata api.