# Can lightning directly call tooling API?

Tags: lightning

I have a issue with Lightning while calling api in lightning, I am getting error unauthorized error and status code 401. But while making call from visual force its working fine.  My question is that does lightning supports tooling api call?

Comment: Please share the code to assist you better else this question is likely getting closed

Comment: It's not officially supported. See [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/110515). There is a hack/workaround, though, if you're daring. They may decide to block it in the future.