# Are there alternatives to cometd for listening to platform events in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-event

This [Trailhead Project](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-platform-events/steps/platform-event-subscribe) uses [cometd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cometd/cometd/3.1.1/cometd-javascript/common/src/main/webapp/js/cometd/cometd.js) to display platform events in Lightning components.

Are there any alternatives I could use to subscribe to platform events in lightning components?

Comment: Where are you planning to use this component? in lightning communities? lightning experience? (both?) and what is your use case?

Comment: The trailhead example disturbes me. An auraEnable function that returns a sessionID token in Lightning context is not supposed to work.

Comment: @SimonPlacentino I was under the same impression about the SessionID. But I cannot remember where I picked that up.

Comment: @glls In my case it is for Lightning Experience. I want to build some charts around platform events in LEX. I found cometd to be quite verbose and was looking for more succinct ways to get the job down.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp Here was my workaround by loading a VFPage https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110515/getting-session-id-in-lightning/111396#111396

Comment: Cheers, I remember the thread. It irks me that trailhead got the session id as seamlessly - the whole discussion prevented me from trying it myself a while ago. -.- Is Streaming API Session or were there changes?

Comment: JSForce is quite lightweight

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is the **only** ways to monitor Platform events (as at Summer '17) is either via the Bayeux messaging protocol with cometd or via Apex triggers subscribed to the events.

In the Dreamforce 2016 [Force.com and Heroku: Building a Connected System Through Platform Events](https://youtu.be/rMAD4yyQX2s?t=20m10s) there was a point on the Roadmap about "Additional messaging protocols" being supported. I heard the following from the youtube video and adjusted based on Google results - AMQP, MQTT, STOMP. 
[image]

However, fast forward to TrailheaDx 2017 with [Event Driven Architectures with Platform Events](https://youtu.be/ihwoG2Pql7Q?t=22m44s) and it no longer shows up on the roadmap.

[image]

So, right now I think if falls into the forward looking statements category.

If you have a request for a specific messaging protocol or something more directly integrated with lightning, bring it up in the dedicated 
[Official: Platform Events](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg) Chatter group or on ideas.