# How do I Call the Salesforce API from a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, soap-api, webservices, metadata-api

I have a requirement to make a call to the [Apex Wrapper Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from a Lightning component. The issue I am facing is that there is currently no native support for acquiring a valid API session ID from an @AuraEnabled method in a Lightning component Apex controller.

The Lightning developer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm#apex_api_calls) states that a named credential can be used in order to bypass this security restriction. However, when I set up a named credential and then pass that named credential reference as the endpoint for the Metadata Service API, I am receiving the following error:

> **"FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is
>   not valid for use with the API faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID
>   faultactor="**.

I have found a potential [work around](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110515/getting-session-id-in-lightning/111396#111396) using Visualforce. However, the thread presenting this work around does not reference the "Named Credentials" feature as an option.

This [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000IBZk#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Developer_Forums&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9060G000000UbJkQAK) also presents the same issue where the documented named credential stops have been followed and the same error is received, but no solution has yet been offered.

I am not able to understand why the named credential feature is not bypassing the session id security measure for Lightning components.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you replaced the {!$Credential.OAuthToken} in APEX?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to manually replace the Session ID in your request body/header .

In named credentials we have options to use the Merge fields in header/body
[image]

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static String getOrgLimits(){
    HTTP http=new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest hres=new HTTPRequest();
    hres.setEndpoint('callout:OWNINSTANCE'+'/services/data/v39.0/limits');
    hres.setMethod('GET');

    hres.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');//Magic happens here
    HttpResponse response=http.send(hres);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    return response.getBody();

}
```

In the above example I am trying to hit my own org's REST endpoint to get LIMITS of my current org. Its native REST calls without using SESSION ID.

In case of SOAP callout you can code something like

```
public class EchoManager {
    public String endpoint_x = 'callout:Echo_Service';
    . . .
    public String echo(String text) {
        WSEchoManager.echo_element request_x = new WSEchoManager.echo_element();
        request_x.text = text;
        this.SessionHeader = new SessionHeader_element();
        this.SessionHeader.sessionId = '{!$Credential.OAuthToken}';//Magic happens here
```

You have to use merge field header for Rest Call
where as you have to use Merge field Body in SOAP call.

You can read more about merge fields here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm

https://blog.enree.co/2016/03/salesforce-apex-lets-play-with-named.html

Comment: cheers ,good day :)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Is this solution still working?

Comment: @Praveen  yes it is

Comment: Can you confirm that this method only works if you have hardcoded a user as the NamedPrincipal in the named credential callout? What I'm asking is can I use this to dynamically get the user session id from the currently logged in user in Apex?

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau there is no way currently of doing this. Otherwise, it would be a security vulnerability.

Comment: @touzoku That's not a security vulnerability... You can always get the currently logged in user's SessionID except in lightning that SessionID is not API enabled because it's an enforced limitation. It is possible in Visualforce, and in both cases the session comes from Salesforce's backend so unless you send it back to the frontend, it is safe.

I would say this method is not great because the namedCredentials only support one identity which means whoever uses that call will be authenticated as the user who made the credentials in the first place. (You could create a dedicated user)

Comment: @EtienneRocheleau it is a security issue in... VisualForce. When Lightning was designed, it was a conscious decision to separate the session ID. Some Metadata changes require explicit consent of an administrator (e.g., adding Remote Site Settings). Allowing SessionID inside Lightning would let LWC to change sensitive org metadata without anyone noticing it. The only reason why it works in VisualForce is, sadly, legacy.

Comment: Understood, but the question is about how to do it in a Lightning component. And the SessionID could have scoped access (like not allowing creation of remote site settings for example?), actually I believe this is already an idea in progress to be able to use the metadata API to do specific calls on specific objects via the session in lightning.