# Unable to aquire valid session id using an apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, session-id

I wrote my own apex class with the following code:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String getSessionId(){
        return UserInfo.getSessionId();
    }
```

This code works when I import it into my Lightning component. I retrieves a session id but it is invalid. If i try to do the same thing inside an apex page it works perfectly and it gives me a working session id. How can I retrieve a working session id?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that session ID? Lightning session IDs cannot be used to authenticate to SFDC to, for example, make metadata API calls.

Comment: Custom app at my company requires the session id for authentication with our services.

Comment: The session you obtain from lightning cannot be used to authenticate against any Salesforce org. The session in itself is otherwise valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [Article](https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/how-to-call-salesforce-api-from-lightning-component/) I was able to extract this method here:

First create a VisualForce page with the name: `currentUserInfoCtrl` 
and then insert into it:

```
<apex:page >
 Start_Of_Session_Id{!$Api.Session_ID}End_Of_Session_Id
</apex:page>
```

Then create a new Apex class that will reference the Apex Page

```java
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String fetchUserSessionId(){
         String sessionId = '';
         // Refer to the Page
         PageReference reportPage = Page.GetSessionIdVF;
         // Get the content of the VF page
         String vfContent = reportPage.getContent().toString();
         System.debug('vfContent '+vfContent);
         // Find the position of Start_Of_Session_Id and End_Of_Session_Id
         Integer startP = vfContent.indexOf('Start_Of_Session_Id') + 'Start_Of_Session_Id'.length(),
         endP = vfContent.indexOf('End_Of_Session_Id');
         // Get the Session Id
         sessionId = vfContent.substring(startP, endP);
         System.debug('sessionId '+sessionId);
         // Return Session Id
         return sessionId;
     }
```

I was able to get a valid session token using this method, and then attaching this apex class to my Lightning Component.

Answer (score 2):

The sessionId obtained from auraEnabled cannot be used to make metadata api calls or the tooling api callouts .

Here are couple of techniques that you can use

1. Set up Named Credential and Auth Provider to obtain sessionId . This is documented in the blog [here](https://eltoro.secure.force.com/apex/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000dq3miIAA)

or

2.Use a proxy visualforce to obtain the SessionId using the global variable .It is documented [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110515/getting-session-id-in-lightning).

You can also use a [service component](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-lightning-api-component) that encapsulates the proxy vf page .This [blog](https://douglascayers.com/2018/09/10/calling-rest-api-from-lightning-components-without-named-credentials/) can help you further .

Comment: I tried to use technique 2 (using proxy visualforce page and it worked fine in unmanaged package, but got (org.apache.commons.httpclient.RedirectException: Maximum redirects (100) exceeded) error in managed package. 
Any idea, why

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps mentioned here - https://www.gscloudsolutions.com/blogpost/Using-Named-Credentials-with-the-Apex-Wrapper-Salesforce-Metadata-API-apex-mdapi?blogpost=true

and It worked for me. 
One modification - While creating connected app, in "Selected OAuth Scopes" select all the options shown in the image here - [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a better version of VF to fetch Session Id without Apex controller

VF Page: UserSessionPage.page

```
<apex:page contentType="application/json">
    {!$Api.Session_ID}
</apex:page>
```

Apex Method:

```
public static String getSessionId() {        
    return  Page.UserSessionPage.getContent().toString();
}
```

Comment: omfg this worked!!  You saved me!! 