# SessionId in LWC for Security Review

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, security-review, session-id

I am using [this](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/11/session-id-of-current-user-in-lightning-context.html) workaround to get the SessionId in my LWC and perform a callout from the JS.
I am concerned about if it will pass the security review for managed packages.
Have someone used it and can confirm?

Also, if used it in managed package, does it work properly or does it face the error pointed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256000/84580) by lambad in the response comment?

UPDATE:

I just took a look at the new Salesforce Managed Package: DevOps Center. And found the following:

[image]

Even themselves are using this hacky approach, so I assume that they could never push back your managed package application during a Security Review due to the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this would not pass the Security Review, and is inappropriate for a managed package, which should not steal the authentication data of its users. If you want to act on behalf of a user, don't impersonate the user, but ask the user to authorize you to act on their behalf: use an OAuth token with a scope agreed to by the user.

It's pretty easy to setup a connected app and get user authorization, and this has the benefit of giving you a refresh token as well. Now with JWT flows, it's even easier, whereas a session id leaves no audit trail, is effectively sharing auth credentials, and can be done silently without the victim's knowledge or consent. Please don't abuse your users' authentication data this way -- this is private user data that does not belong to a managed package. Rely on your own authentication data and have users authorize you to act on their behalf.

Comment: The problem for this approach is that I need to perform the callout from my LWC javascript. I can not do it in Apex. And I don't know any way to pass the named credential information to the controller. Do you have any suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: Also, so far we are using the same approach but from real VF pages so, what is the difference? That has passed sec reviews so far, and I do not see less risk there or more risk here.

Comment: It would fail the security review in VF or LWC, this is not a specific rule only for LWC.  But with lightning there was an attempt to more systematically stop the abuse we were seeing with third party apps grabbing user session ids. For specific advice I would ask what you are trying to do that can't be done with an OAuth token but requires the user's sid. If you can do it with a token, store the token server side and pass it to the client. With JWT, you don't even need to store any tokens, but can mint them on demand and pass them to the client.

Comment: This video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cViU2-xVscA

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I will try that way and take a look at the video.

Comment: I managed to get what I needed from this video. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobertSussland If Apex in a managed package authenticates into the "local" Salesforce using a connected app, would it pass security for the apex to pass the connected app session ID to an external system