# System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401] from Apex Controller

Tags: apex, httprequest

I have the following code, that retrieves picklist values dependent on a record type:

```
public static List<String> getPicklistValuesByRecordType(String objectType, String recordTypeId, String fieldName) {
    //Endpoint
    system.debug('objectType : ' + objectType);
    system.debug('recordTypeId : ' + recordTypeId);
    system.debug('fieldName : ' + fieldName);
    String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    endpoint += '/services/data/v41.0';
    endpoint += '/ui-api/object-info/{0}/picklist-values/{1}/{2}';
    endpoint = String.format(endpoint, new String[]{ objectType, recordTypeId, fieldName });
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(endpoint,'UTF-8');

    //HTTP Request send
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    system.debug('endpoint: ' + endpoint);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    system.debug('res: ' + res);
    //Parse response
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    Map<String,Object> root = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    if(!root.containsKey('values')){ 
        return result; 
    }
    List<Object> pValues = (List<Object>)root.get('values');
    for(Object pValue : pValues){
        Map<String,Object> pValueMap = (Map<String,Object>)pValue;
        result.add((String)pValueMap.get('value'));

    }
    System.debug(result);
    return result;
}
```

When i run the following code from Execute Anonymous Window, i receive

> System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]

But when running it from apex code that's being called by a component, i receive

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]

Maybe its because i can't get UserInfo.getSessionId() from the code?

Please advise.

Comment: If you are using OAuth for Authorization, did you setup Connected App?

Comment: Didn't know i should, i will read about it. Thanks.

Comment: SessionId is not available in @AuraEnabled methods https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110515/getting-session-id-in-lightning

Comment: It's not @AuraEnabled, But called from an AuraEnabled Function. still won't be avaiable that way?

Answer (score 4):

Which API version is your code saved under? Direct access to SF's API from Apex was improved in Winter '19 (v44). If your code is older, that might explain why it doesn't work. Also, their example code used Bearer instead of OAuth in the Authorization header:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()
   + '/services/data/v44.0/limits');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

See https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use getOrgDomainUrl() to interact with Salesforce REST and SOAP APIs in Apex code. Get endpoints for User Interface API calls, for creating and customizing picklist value sets and custom fields, and more.

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()
   + '/services/data/v44.0/limits');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```