# This session is not valid for use with the REST API

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

I am getting this when try to use Salesforce REST API from it's apex

`[{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`

Approach I am using is described here: https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/call-salesforce-rest-api-from-apex/

It works for Admins, but does not work for all users.
Any ideas how to solve this? Is it lack of permissions issue?

Comment: Is the permission `Api Enabled` on the user's profile marked true?

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/110515/2984), as I suspect that is your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Unfortunately it also doesn't work for non-admin. User can get vf page manually and see its content but it doesnt work from Apex code

Comment: I am curious why it works fine with UserInfo.getSessionID() on Developer edition, but doesn't work on a sandbox