# How to call salesforce service end point as current user while using Named credentials as LWC is the invoker based on user action

Tags: apexrest, namedcredentials

What is the best way to call salesforce service end point as current user. As Named credential authenticates as one specific user who initially authorizes it.

I am calling my apex helper method from Lwc and lightning session ids not valid for api usage. Salesforce recommends to do it with Named credentials which is not suitable for my use case.

My use case is need to get the List view describe for forming query with List view filters as where condition in my soql. if list view is private(Only visible to me as sharing setting on List view) calling as named credential authorized user results in no access to list view describe. I don't want take route of id password authentication flow.

Appreciate the help

[Getting Session ID in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110515/getting-session-id-in-lightning/111396#111396) this one was close case but does not answer my question or use case