# Bypass the "Apex type not found" error

Tags: wsdl2apex

We implemented few times ago a webservice between Salesforce and an external application. It worked like a charm for the last weeks.

Today, I have this error :

> Apex type not found for element creditorType

In the WSDL, there is no field `creditorType`. I asked the IT support of the application, they said me that they released a new WSDL during the last days, with this new field.

The only option I have right now is to insert the new WSDL into Salesforce. Ok, that's done.

But is there an option to bypass this error? I mean, is there a way to say to Salesforce "Ok, you don't know this field, but please don't crash and go to the next one"?

The WSDL2Apex generated a lot of code. Is there something to do with it?

```
private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:com:...','true','false'};
private String[] mandateResponse_type_info = new String[]{'mandateResponse','.....',null,'0','1','false'}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information as to where the error occurred? I'm wondering if your doing some strict parsing based on the generated classes from the wsdl.

Comment: It seems that the error occured when parsing the response, as the full message error is : `Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element creditorCode` and that I can found data I sent in the external app @techbusinessman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't bypass it when using wsdl2Apex and the corresponding `WebServiceCallout.invoke()` call. It expects to be able to deserialize the entire response message according to what was defined in the WSDL.

Ideally the web service you are integrating with would be versioned. Then you would only need to update the Salesforce implementation when updating the version you integrate with. Salesforce follows this approach with their WSDLs.

You could potentially handle a variable response by manually parsing the responses in Apex. This means using an HttpRequest based on the WSDL. See [How to create HttpRequest body as plain string from WSDL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/60510/102)

I don't think you would ever be able to handle all the possible problems that could occur with changes to the WSDL if the API isn't versioned. They could easily add a required field that your wouldn't know about, change a data type, or remove something that you need. You might buy yourself some flexibility, but it won't always be sufficient.

Comment: Indeed, i don't think httprequest would help a lot, as I think we would have issues later. I'll make sure that our partner noticed us when doing an update on the WSDL ! Thanks !